# Matplotlib annotate/text: How can I set alpha transparency for facecolor and edgecolor separately?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, text, alpha

I'm using the matplotlib `plt.text` function to add a textbox to my histogram. In the `bbox` argument I specify the `boxstyle`, `facecolor`, `edgecolor`, and `alpha`. However when I run this and display the plot, both the face of the box and its edge become transparent with respect to `alpha`. This slightly changes the both colors and I would like to just keep my edge solid. Does anyone know a way to set alpha such that the border stays opaque (`alpha=1`) but the facecolor can be set at any value (`alpha = [0,1]`).

Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(x=data, bins='auto', color='#0504aa', alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.85)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.75)

textstr = '\n'.join((
    r'$n=%.2f$' % (len(data), ),
    r'$\mu=%.2f$' % (round(statistics.mean(data), 4), ),
    r'$\mathrm{median}=%.2f$' % (round(statistics.median(data), 4), ),
    r'$\sigma=%.2f$' % (round(statistics.pstdev(data), 4), )))

ax.text(0.05, 0.95, textstr, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=14,
        verticalalignment='top', bbox=dict(boxstyle='square,pad=.6',facecolor='lightgrey', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.7))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first compute the RGBA sequence of both of your colors, then alter the alpha parameter **only** for the `facecolor` and then pass the modified RGBA tuples to the `text` function

```
from matplotlib import colors

# Rest of your code

fc = colors.to_rgba('lightgrey')
ec = colors.to_rgba('black')

fc = fc[:-1] + (0.7,) # <--- Change the alpha value of facecolor to be 0.7

ax.text(0.05, 0.95, textstr, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=14,
        verticalalignment='top', bbox=dict(boxstyle='square,pad=.6',
        facecolor=fc, edgecolor=ec)) # <--- Assign the face and edgecolors
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify colors with alpha values
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colors.html
For RGB with alpha you can use this, any number between 0 and 1
`(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3)`